# Adding multiple indexes to avoid skip/limit in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pagination

Let's say I have a MongoDB's database with millon of records having a City name, a User name and an activity.

```
City        | User   | Action
------------+--------+-------------------
Gotham      | Batman | Fight with Joker
Gotham      | Batman | Fight with Penguin
Gotham      | Robin  | Fight with Joker
Gotham      | Robin  | Fight with Riddler
Springfield | Homer  | Working
Springfield | Homer  | Moe's bar
Springfield | Bart   | At school
```

I want a fast paging method to show data in a web site listing all results, results by city or results by city and user. Although I have the main indexes by city & name, still using the `db.find(...).skip((page_number - 1) * rows_per_page).limit(rows_per_page)` method is slow.

Because no record is deleted, my approch to circumvent the performance issue, is to add some extra rows with incremental values and several new indexes:

```
City        | User   | Action             | Global Index | Index By City | Index By City & User
------------+--------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------
Gotham      | Batman | Fight with Joker   | 1            | 1             | 1
Gotham      | Batman | Fight with Penguin | 2            | 2             | 2
Gotham      | Robin  | Fight with Joker   | 3            | 3             | 1
Gotham      | Robin  | Fight with Riddler | 4            | 4             | 2
Springfield | Homer  | Working            | 5            | 1             | 1
Springfield | Homer  | Moe's bar          | 6            | 2             | 2
Springfield | Bart   | At school          | 7            | 3             | 1
```

So I do paging by `Global Index`, `City + Index By City` or `City + User + Index By City & User`

Is this approach good or horrible? Or is there a better method?

Comment: You don't have an existing field which stores the date and time of record insertion that you could use instead?

Comment: Does the explain plan of the slow query show it using the index?

Comment: Hi @Colin'tHart I could, but data is not inserted at a constant rate.

Comment: Hi @Joe using the index works But real data has several fields and paginated views so I have to apply a similar approach to all of the views which, in turn, leads to having several "sequential index fields" and indexes on them. The method works but would like to know if there is a different approach than this sort of hack hack.

Comment: Run explain to see why the find.skip.limit is slow.  If it is properly indexed, the number of documents examined should be the same as the number returned.

Comment: To avoid `skip` because it is slow when you start to skip lots of documents (because MongoDB processes all of them) I created the index. But I'm not sure if creating lots of indexes can lead to the same issue sooner or later because the overhead of adding data with lots of indexes.

Comment: There is a limit of 64 indexes per collection.  Yes, inserting/deleting a document or updating an indexed field also requires updating each index, which is a non-zero cost.  I suspect that the number of times a document is written is significantly less than the number of times it is read, so indexing should be an overall win for performance.